# iOS header design guidelines

Tags: ios, design-guidelines

Client requires total 7 action buttons on the navigation bar of the app Home Screen. plus more action buttons on tapping of those buttons. and Additionally 5 menus for tab-bar.
Is there any risk in approval of this design? Can this type of design get approval?

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/) it is mentioned that we should not crowed the navigation bar with too many icons. But is it necessary that we cannot have?

[description on iOS design guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwosW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a view for creating a custom bar with several buttons. Apple will pass it.